# How to manage a screencast with two Android devices?

Tags: remote-control

I need to do an oral presentation which involves demoing an Android application that requires showing two devices at the same time. I know about the [Android Screencast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/) as a way to capture the Android screen to my computer output but don't know how to manage two devices.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both devices are rooted, you can use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), which offers an...

> Realtime Android screen (experimental feature, root permission required)
>   View your Android's screen, take a screenshot, or even record a screencast.

As you connect to the device using a web browser, you can just have two browser windows open - et voila, both devices should be shown simultaneously.

Alternativ solution: [droid VNC server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc) (and other VNC servers). Again, requires rooted device -- plus a VNC client on the computer.

There are several more solutions, but they mostly fall in either of the mentioned categories.